# How to handle target-specific methods, e.g. WinForms or Blazor, in .NET Standard library project?

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, blazor, .net-standard-2.0

I would like to share code between a .NET Framework 4.7.2 WinForms and a .NET 6.0 Blazor application using a .NET Standard 2.0 library project. Should I use Dependency Injection in order to implement methods within the library which depend on the target application? E.g. when displaying a user message either using WinForms or Blazor?

If Dependency Injection is the way to go, could you provide an outline on how to implement the above example? Can it be done without a Dependency Injection Container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this kind of thing a lot with my apps that are cross-platform between WinForms and things like Xamarin for example. One of the easier ways I've found to do this is to make the portable library class `abstract`, compelling the client to inherit the class supplying the platform dependent code. It can also be handy to make your client identify itself with a `RuntimePlatform` enum. Alternatively, `virtual` methods would work but can produce "silent fails" unless they throw `NotImplementedException` at which point why not `abstract` it.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace net_standard_portable_library
{
    public enum RuntimePlatform
    {
        WinOS,
        Android,
        iOS,
        Web,
        MAUI,
    }
    public abstract class BusinessLogic
    {
        public BusinessLogic(RuntimePlatform platform) => RuntimePlatform = platform;
        protected abstract Task<bool> DisplayAlert(string title, string message, string accept, string cancel);
        public async Task<bool> TestPopup()
        {
            bool result = await DisplayAlert(
                title: "Demo", 
                message: $"Is {RuntimePlatform} popup visible?", accept: "Yes", cancel: "No");

            Debug.WriteLine($"Dialog returned {result}");
            return result;
        }
        public RuntimePlatform RuntimePlatform { get; }
    }
}
```

---

Another option I've had success with is having `interface` or `delegate` members  in the PCL lib that the platform-specific client can populate.

---

**WinForms client**

[image: winforms client]

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using net_standard_portable_library;

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonTestLibrary.Click += onClickTestLibrary;
    }
    private void onClickTestLibrary(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _ = _lib.TestPopup();
    }
    // Consume library
    BusinessLogic _lib = new PlatformBusinessLogic(RuntimePlatform.WinOS);
}
class PlatformBusinessLogic : BusinessLogic
{
    public PlatformBusinessLogic(RuntimePlatform platform) : base(platform) { }

    protected override async Task<bool> DisplayAlert(string title, string message, string accept, string cancel)
    {
        var buttons = $"{accept}.{cancel}".ToUpper();
        switch (buttons) 
        {
            case "YES.NO":
                bool result = false;
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    result = DialogResult.Yes.Equals
                    (
                        MessageBox.Show(text: message, caption: title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                    );
                });
                return result;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException($"TODO: Handler for {buttons}.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Android client**

[image: maui client]

```
using net_standard_portable_library;

namespace maui_client_of_portable_library
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // Consume library
        BusinessLogic _lib = new PlatformBusinessLogic(RuntimePlatform.MAUI);

        private void onClickTestLibrary(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ = _lib.TestPopup();
        }
    }
    class PlatformBusinessLogic : BusinessLogic
    {
        public PlatformBusinessLogic(RuntimePlatform platform) : base(platform) { }

        protected override async Task<bool> DisplayAlert(string title, string message, string accept, string cancel)
        {
            return await Shell.Current.CurrentPage.DisplayAlert(title, message, accept, cancel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Important note about inheritance-based approach. In many cases in the platform-specific code, such as Xamarin.iOS you will be forced to inherit your classes from the platform-specific classes provided by the library/framework, such as `NSViewController`. And C# does not support multiple inheritance. So, if you need to share some view-related control logic, you will probably don't want to use inheritance as described in the answer. Interface-based way with IoC/DI looks preferable here.

Comment: @Serg I want to make sure I understand your comment. That is, I appreciate the general concern but why would the PCL lib need any such dependencies? For example, the code I used to test this answer [[clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/platform-client-of-portable-library.git)] works, and uses PCL library `net-6-portable-library` that is entirely without platform references. I've done the same thing with `NETStandard`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The comment not much about the exact answer and code samples, but about idea mentioned into the answer. Let's assume that we need the same view for Win & Mac. So we want to share as most view-related logic as we can and move it into PCL. A first possible attempt may be to create something like `ViewControllerBase` into PCL and then extend it for each plafrom with UI added and some platform-speific details implemented. And this will not work because you will need to inhernit, let's say, `From` under windows and `NSWindowControlller/NSViewController` under mac.

Comment: In case if we need to extend some clean business-logic with platform-specific details as in the sample from the answer, there is no problems.